# Trying to serve csv files from Django

Tags: django

I try to serve a (6KB) generated file. I can do it in development but not in production:

My view is like this:

```
def download_export_view(request, ref):
    selection = models.Selection.objects.get(id=ref, user=request.user)

    filename = ref + '.csv'
    filepath = os.path.join(EXPORTS_DIR, filename)
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filepath))

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(filepath), 8192),
                                     content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0])
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (filename,)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filepath)

    return response
```

I am sure that the file path is right because I get 200 Status and no exception (like FileNotFoundError), but my browser does not get the file.

Comment: I have tested with Chrome and it does not fails! But it takes a very long time to be start downloading.

Comment: Best way seems to be letting nginx to do the work. For it I used X-Accel-Redirect. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704712/django-nginx-x-accel-redirect-for-protected-files-on-webfaction#answer-28716254 I find this more logical.

Answer (score 0):

For me this snippet addressed the issue.

```
 ...
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % (filename,)
wrapper.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
response['Content-Length'] = wrapper.tell()
return response
 ...
```